# Symfony Question: How to get/read the HTML content of a page?

Tags: php, symfony1

So, I have a actions.class.php and have the function like that:

```
public function executeGetHTML($request)
{
   $pageName = $request->getParameter('name', '');
}
```

I do not want to output the content of getHTMLSuccess.php

instead, depending on the request, I need to get the HTML code of another page (without processing it ..e.g. filtering it..etc).  Actually, the page content will be output in JSONP within a JSON variable. e.g.

For example, I call  /getHTML?name=abc

and abc.html (or abc.php) has the content:

```
<div>Hello, my beautiful world</div>
```

then I will get the page content of Hello, my beautiful world

and output it as:  mycallback({content:'Hello, my beautiful world'});

I know I can do file_get_content(...)  but it sounds like very heavy to do file read explicitly while symfony should already cache and know .

include / require won't work in this... so, is there a light-weight way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the getPresentationFor method (http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfController#method_getpresentationfor)

```
public function executeGetHTML($request) {
  $pageName = $request->getParameter('name', '');

  $html = $this->getPresentationFor('module', 'action');
}
```

This will return the output for the requested module/action rather than outputing it to screen

Answer (score 2):

Didnt work for me in symfony 1.4.14, until I used getController():

```
$html = $this->getController()->getPresentationFor('module', 'action');
```

And also to pass parameters to the action:

```
$this->getRequest()->setParameter('parameter_name', value);
```

Another way to pass parameters:

```
$html = $this->getController()->getPresentationFor('module', 'action?id=123');
```